# $A \setminus B \cup C = A \setminus (B \cup C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

$A \setminus B \cup C$ or $A \setminus (B \cup C)$?

Sorry as this is a very soft question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Are these two things generally considered the same?

Comment: Usually $A\setminus B\cup C$ is considered meaningless.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $(A\setminus B)\cup C$ is the same as $A\setminus (B\cup C)$, in particular when $C$ is non-empty. (If this is what you are asking anyway)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $(A\setminus B)\cup C$ by $A\setminus B\cup C$, then no they aren't. $(A\setminus B)\cup C$ will contain everything in $C$, but $A\setminus (B\cup C)$ contains nothing from $C$ (since it only contains things which are neither in $B$ nor in $C$).

Comment: I suspect OP is asking if there is a default "order of operations" that would kick in if parentheses are not explicitly provided

Comment: Perhaps. If so, then it's a duplicate. If not, not. The OP is probably best placed to confirm what they were asking.